# get the lowest value in a set min()

Tags: php, integer, min

In PHP I'm trying to get the lowest value off every set.

For example:

```
01|15|59 
01|47|6 
 1|17|20 
 1|32|34
```

Then from every set I want the lowest integer.

What is the best way to do this, I was thinking trying it with min() but it only returns 19.

Please help me

Comment: 19? 19 doesn't even exist in that data. What have you tried? Post your code

Comment: You can do it with a foreach loop and test each value and return the lowest, you can build array and use php `min()` function...but how can you get 19 it's not even here? Show the code please, and how to you get those set of value? It's a string? An array fo value?

Comment: `function athleticComputerNerd() {
  echo min(01|15|59, 01|47|6, 1|17|20, 1|32|34, 2|3|17);
  
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your data is a string in a array, then try this

```
<?php
$data = ["01|15|59", "01|47|6", "1|17|20", "1|32|34"];
$min = [];
foreach($data as $dt)
{
    $min[] = (int) min(explode("|", $dt));
}
var_dump($min);
?>
```